How to Prevent Page Re-Rendering on Route Change with React, Shadcn-UI, and React-Table?
I am building a dashboard application using React, Shadcn-UI, and React-Router-Dom. The dashboard has a sidebar for navigation and various pages displaying data tables using React-Table.
const App = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <ProtectedRoute><RootLayout /></ProtectedRoute>,
      children: [
        { index: true, element: <Dashboard /> },
        { path: "/rolls", element: <RollsPage /> },
        { path: "/slits", element: <SlitsPage /> },
      ],
    },
    { path: "*", element: <>404</> },
  ]);
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default App;

RootLayout.jsx:
function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <SidebarProvider>
      <AppSidebar />
      <main>
        <Header />
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </SidebarProvider>
  );
}

export default memo(RootLayout);

RollsPage.jsx:
function RollsPage() {
  return <RollTable />;
}
export default memo(RollsPage);

Question:
How can I prevent page re-rendering when navigating between routes in this setup? Are there better ways to optimize rendering for complex tables with actions and buttons in columns? Any tips on React-Router or React-Table configurations would be greatly appreciated!

I don't see any overt issue in the code you have shared here. What exactly is the issue or problem? What is rerendering when you navigate? Where and how are you effecting navigation changes? Please [edit] to clarify so readers better understand what you are asking for specific help with.

in each page like rolls or slits evet i have minimized the table inside i have but all rolls and slits are rerenders and when i change the page even the sidebar active design is not changed directly it waits untill all the page is renders and then changes.
my pages are having big data and much design
even when i use lazyloading and wrap the routes with Suspence it effects only on first time opening the second time it will be a 1000ms lack

If you are navigating between "/rolls" and "/slits" then obviously RollsPage and SlitsPage will remount/rerender when their respective routes are navigated to. This is normal behavior.

is there anyway to show a loading untill it rerenders then? i tried useEffect but i thought its not best practice

Like if you are fetching data on either page, you want to render some loading UI? Yes, that is possible.

the problem is im using rtk query and i dont refetch data always cause we dont need it

So what is the actual issue or problem you have then? RTK will cache queried results for a bit of time, so if you navigate away and back to a component with an active subscription it will just receive the cached data, otherwise if the cache is empty RTK will fetch the data. RTK hooks also include the isLoading/isFetching metadata so it's trivial to render loading UI. This all doesn't seem relevant to React-Router or component re-rendering though.

You are saying that i have to make a better performance inside the table and data. and there is nothing to do with react router right?

Perhaps, but it's also not clear at all if any actual issue exists to improve.
